# gather from tidyr compains about object not found

Tags: r, tidyr

I had this snippet of working code:

```
number_of_columns <-  dim(resultsper)[2]
resultsper <- resultsper %>% gather(c(5:number_of_columns), key = "Scenario", value = "Value")
```

This used to work fine, but now, I get the message

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'number_of_columns' not found.

If I run

```
resultsper <- resultsper %>% gather <- (c(5:11), key = "Scenario", value = "Value")
```

It works again, but this is not what I want. I tried gather_ but this also doesn't work. It might be an update of tidyr, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks in advance

Renger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in *tidyr 0.7.0*, selecting rules are more strict.  A review of all the changes in versino 0.7.0 can be found in [this article](http://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/08/tidyr-0.7.0/).

In a nutshell, when using a **context expression** (i.e., using information outside the dataset) you must be explicit on where to find the objects by using the quasiquotation operator `!!`.

Here is an example of what that would look like in your scenario.

```
number_of_columns =  ncol(mtcars)

mtcars %>% gather("Scenario", "Value", !! 5:number_of_columns)
```